# PS4 save data transfer

Tags: ps4

I recently got a new ps4 and I was wondering if there was any way I could transfer a specific game/games without transferring over the entire system (other that thumb drive transfer)

Answer (score 1):

You can very easily upload your save data online and then download it on your new ps4 as long as you're using the same psn account. [official guide](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/data_system.html)